# Add an IF statement in SUMMARIZE formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Objective:**

I would like to add an `IF` condition to my query, but i'm not sure how. In other words, substitute the MAX expression for the IF statement below

The IF condition is:

```
IF(
    'Data Model'[amount] = 'Data Model'[orderTotalPrice],
    'Data Model'[amount] - 'Data Model'[shipping_price] - 'Data Model'[total_tax],
    'Data Model'[amount]
)
```

**My query:**

```
VAR Summary =
 CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE (
        'Data Model',
        'Data Model'[orderId],
        "MaxValue", CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Data Model'[amount] ),
            'Data Model'[kind] = "refund",
            'Data Model'[status] = "success"
        )
    ),USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Data Model'[trx_date], DateTable[Date] ))
RETURN
    SUMX ( Summary, [MaxValue] )
```

Comment: What happens if you just substitute the MAX() with the IF()??

Comment: @teylyn it doesnt let me